Use of "on" at beginning of sentence
Does the word "on" have a meaning "when" used at the beginning of a sentence?

61' On the break, Sterling chases down the right and lays the ball
into Gundogan's path, but the midfielder's shot on the turn from 20
yards spirals over the bar.

So "on the break" means "when the break."

It means "when the break happens" or "at the time of the break". "on the X" is usually used when X causes an abrupt change in the game state.

Related to the used mentioned by Barmar is to use on to introduce a particular "play" in a game or a particular strategic action:  On the offsides-trap, the defensive backs step forward to put the strikers offsides.

@TimR Does "on" still mean "when" in your example sentence? On the offsides-trap = when the offsides-trap.

It doesn't mean "when"; "on the break" is an idiom used in football. See the OED or this. What do you think the sentence means? What does "break" mean? The meaning of break is here: 16.4.

Shakita, that is a prepositional phrase, like on the chair. Here, "on the break" means when the ball is available to another player. Prepositional phrases are often placed at the beginning of a sentence if it is closer to explaining what the subject is doing.  [It's offside trap, I think]

@Shakila: An accurate paraphrase would be "when executing the offsides-trap".   Compare the phrase: "On three" which means "I will count 'one, two, three' and when I say the word 'three' we will suddenly act together", such as when a group of people are pulling a tow rope, or lifting something heavy together, or jumping as daredevils off a cliff into water below. etc.

"On the break" is an idiom here meaning "while making a break" (it can have other slightly different meanings in different contexts).
The meaning of the sentence is exactly the same if "on the break" is moved to elsewhere: "Sterling chases down the right on the break and lays the ball ..." or "Sterling, on the break, chases down the right and lays the ball ..."
The idiom is similar to "on the run", which means "while running".
